Is there a way we can indicate an answerers "non native speaker" status?
I am often writing "not a native speaker!" or equivalent on my posts. Perhaps there is a way this can be indicated on the user's profile and then all their posts are marked automatically in some way.
I recommend this be an opt-in feature, don't want people persecuted for choosing not to indicate they are a non-native speaker.

This has been proposed and re-proposed and re-proposed and re-proposed and re-proposed again in other sites (just a few examples) and the answer, as you could see, was always the same: no.
There is an alternative way for you to show it, though, which is not exactly the same but it still works (I use it). In other words, your personal profile. Write it there. It's the only option.
